# Excel find first name formula using if error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

COLUMN D contains a set of full names. In column E, I am using the formula to extract the first name only but want to add in the IF ERROR formula to ignore values if there is nothing in the cell. The formula I am using is: =LEFT(D3,SEARCH(" ",D3))

Can anyone advise how to add in the IF ERROR to this please to return blank if there is no data.

Thank you,

chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [support page for IFERROR()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611), we see the format is

```
IFERROR(value, value_if_error)
```

The formula you have in your question is the `value` part. What do you want it to return if there's nothing in the cell? Blank? If so, it would look like this:

```
IFERROR(LEFT(D3,SEARCH(" ",D3)),"")
```

Keep in mind, though, that `SEARCH()` only returns an error if it can't find a space. There can be text in the cell and it will still return an error if there isn't a space. In that case, you may want to return the entire cell instead of nothing, presuming that no space means only the first name has been saved.

```
IFERROR(LEFT(D3,SEARCH(" ",D3)),D3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that formula is perfect

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, slightly adjusted...

`=IFERROR(LEFT(D3,SEARCH(" ",TEXT(D3,"@ "))),"")`

Will produce "" (empty string) for an empty D3 and the full text if there is no space in the actual value in D3.

Numbers not copied; change the format code in TEXT inf you want those included as "valid input" (to be copied).